# Command in section names with multiple "fallbacks" to other commands

Tags: macros, sectioning

I want to write a command that may takes 0 or 1 arguments, and use it in `\section`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter

\def\mycmd{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@with[0]}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{{\color{red}\texorpdfstring{\sout{#2}}{#2}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

% This works:
\mycmd{Test 0}
\mycmd[1]{Test 1}

% This does not compile:
\section{\mycmd{Test 0}}
\section{\mycmd[1]{Test 1}}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the initial command `\mycmd` uses `\ifnextchar` and falls back to `\@with` and I think this is what causes the problem. It tried using `\texorpdfstring` but I did not manage to get it working.

The exact error I get is:

> ! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
>
> <inserted text>
>
> \par
>
> l.21 \section{\mycmd{Test 0}}

Edit: The final goal is to implement a system of versioning so that `\rem{}` is colored or removed depending on another variable and having multiple level of version (`\rem[0]{}`, `\rem[1]{}`). I already have lots of files with the `\rem{}` working but I would like to add the extra arguments without having to replace everything with `\rem[0]`.

Comment: I think it would be better if you state your goal, instead of asking for help to implement something very very strange. There is another way to the wanted result.

Comment: @Johannes_B Post edited.

Comment: you get no error if you define the command using standard constructs `\newcommand\mycmd[2][0]{{\color{red}\texorpdfstring{\sout{#2}}{#2}}}` but that may not be what you want (hyperref warns a bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the optional argument test to be protected, but the `\texorpdfstring` to be seen before protection so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ulem}


\def\mycmd#1#{\mycmdy{#1}}
\def\mycmdy#1#2{\texorpdfstring{\mycmdx#1{#2}}{#2}}
\newcommand\mycmdx[2][0]{\textcolor{red}{\sout{#2}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

% This works:
\mycmd{Test 0}
\mycmd[1]{Test 1}

% This does not compile:
\section{\mycmd{Test 0}}
\section{\mycmd[1]{Test 1}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I never know when to use `\def` or `\newcommand`... By using a single `\newcommand` macro, I managed to have everything working without `\texorpdfstring` (typically, calling directly `\mycmdx` in your snippet). Do you think this may cause a problem later?

Answer (score 0):

And here an alternate syntax that you might like

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\setremnone#1{\long\expandafter\def\csname rem#1\endcsname##1{}}
\def\setremcolor#1#2{\long\expandafter\def\csname rem#1\endcsname##1{\texorpdfstring{\textcolor{#2}{\sout{##1}}}{##1}}}
\def\rem#1#{\csname rem\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax0\else#1\fi\endcsname}

\setremcolor1{red}
\setremcolor0{blue}

\begin{document}

\rem{Test 0}
\rem1{Test 1}

\section{\rem{Test 0}}
\section{\rem1{Test 1}}

\setremnone0
\setremcolor1{orange}

\rem{Test 0}
\rem1{Test 1}

\end{document}
```

so `\rem0{content}` just gobbles the content and `\rem1{whatever}` colors `whatever` in `red`; or whatever you decide with `\setremcolor` and `\setremnone`.